# Visual Studio not picking up change made in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2017

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019 and have a stored procedure on a database in SQL Server 2017. I have modified the procedure to change one of the JOINed tables to a different one and this reflects when I execute the stored procedure.

However, when I run a report using this procedure within Visual Studio, the old data appears. I have tried refreshing the fields in the dataset, as well as closing and opening the report and Visual Studio itself.

Is there some way for the report to pick up the change that I'm missing?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Please share your code for better understanding

Comment: If your using Visual Studio to preview SSRS report, it will show you cached data, you need to refresh the report within Visual Studio to get the new data.

Comment: @Dordi You gave me a brainwave! I deleted the DATA file for the report which forced through the refresh. Thank you!